# Prepend text to input value on form submit

Tags: javascript

What would be the best way to prepend text to an input value on form submit? I’m presuming Javascript?

I have an input on a form where the user will add a numeric value, but on submit I want the value to be prepended with the test 'Invoice Number ';

Comment: I'm guessing you are submitting the data to a php backend.Why not simply append it there?

Comment: No, I'm actually passing the data off to a payment gateway unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if it's the best way, but I would do something like this (untested):

```
<script>
function PerpendText(name) {
  var val = document.getElementsByName(name)[0];
  val.value = "Invoice Number:" + val.value;  
}

</script>
<form onsubmit="PerpendText('num')">
  Enter invoice number: <input type="text" name="num">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9j3cky04/).

Comment: @SatejS thanks for the comment. Now I use `value` attribute. EDITED.